# How can I pass a value to a variable in LESS?

Tags: html, css, less, mixins

I'd like to pass a value to a variable in LESS.  How can I do this?

Here's some sample code.  I'd like to pass the values in `.className()` to the variable `@varValue`.

```
@defaultWidth: 10px;
.className(@varValue: 1) {
    width: (@defaultWidth * @varValue);
    background: green;
}

.sample {

    background: blue;
    height: 10px;

    .filled_1     { .className(1); }
    .filled_2     { .className(2); }
    .filled_3     { .className(3); }
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="sample">
    <div class="filled_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what you wrote works. Did you run into any problem? I compiled it at http://winless.org/online-less-compiler and it compiled properly.

Comment: Well, how about that. I guess it does.  Looks like I have a problem with my local LESS compiler.  It's throwing a fit about undefined @varValue.  Thanks.  Would you like to make your comment an answer and get some points?

Comment: Thanks, but I am here for the answers, not the points. You can mark my comment as "This comment adds something useful to the post". I have no idea if it grants points or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Guy Morgrabi stated in the comment above, it's an issue with different LESS compiler versions.  Guy should get the credit, but for the others visiting, you should know the answer.